# How much does reputation matter?

Tags: discussion, reputation-bias

Should I treat higher rep users differently when flagging/downvoting questions?

---

I recently found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063983/how-to-prohibit-null-for-java-compiler) asked by a high(er than average) rep user.

The question appears to be a clear case of requesting on off-site resource.

In light of the askers rep, 7k which is much higher than my very modest 1.5k. I strayed from my usual protocol, which is to downvote and flag such questions. Instead I merely left a comment recommending an edit to focus the question.

The user still has not edited their question and it seems to have died. I want to respect the contribution they have made to the site in the past. However, I don't think their question represents very much value in the current state of the site.

---

Here is the question again: [How to prohibit null for Java compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063983/how-to-prohibit-null-for-java-compiler)

Comment: I'd like to think that we should judge questions based on the content of the question itself, not the status of the asker. Their reputation / other stats may give some insight into where they are coming from, but I wouldn't refrain from flagging a bad question just because the user has a high reputation. Bad questions are bad.

Comment: *asked by a high(er than average) rep user...appears to be a clear case of requesting on off-site resource.* - That actually happens more often that you'd think. Sometimes it's the case that someone gained a lot of rep years ago, came back, and didn't realize the rules had changed but I've seen high rep users with recently activity do this.

Comment: That said, that question asks if there's a *way* to do that, not for a *tool* to do that. It doesn't read like a find request to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I treat higher rep users differently when flagging/downvoting questions?

Certainly not. Downvote/Close vote.

You should concentrate on question contents judging about quality regardless of the users rep.

It may be hard to judge for higher rep users questions since these could come up needing some implied background. But nevertheless the OP needs to make it clear in 1st place.

Comment: Indeed.  Very high rep. users have been known to post total howlers, (yes, you know who you are:).